# Access to android OS settings

Tags: java, android, android-settings

how can I get access to the Android OS settings from source code?
I get access to some settings like check Internet connection

```
private void checkIntenet() {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        networkInfo = null;
        networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.activeNetwork) + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.available) + " " + networkInfo.isAvailable() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.connected) + " " + networkInfo.isConnected() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append(getResources().getString(R.string.extra) + "" + networkInfo.getExtraInfo() + "\n" + "\n");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "networkInfo is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

but I can't get access to Android OS settings

Comment: which kind of settings do u nee ?

Comment: what exactly you need ?
i mean what do you want to access ?
we have access to almost everything but we can not make any kind of changes on settings part using android-sdk,

Comment: I need to check the backup setting (Menu-Setting-Privacy-Back up my data)

Comment: if you want to make changes to anything related to settings you need to work on framework part of OS

Comment: What kind of settings are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

Answer (score 0):

There are few hidden API
you can access those apis here http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/